# Provider function called but no change notified

Tags: flutter, provider

I have a widget in my settings screen something like this:

```
Widget autoplay()
{
   return  ChangeNotifierProvider<AutoplayToggle>(
               create: (context) => AutoplayToggle(),
               child: Consumer<AutoplayToggle>(
                  builder: (context, provider, child) {
                     return Container(
                               color: provider.isPause ? accent : primary,
                               width: 45,
                               child: Switch.adaptive(
                                   value: isPause,
                                   onChanged: (value) async {
                                      setState(() {
                                      isPause= value;
                                      });
                                   await UserPrefs.setAutoplay(isPause);
                                   provider.toggleAutoplay();
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
}
```

and this is my class:

```
class AutoplayToggle with ChangeNotifier{

   bool isPause = false;

   void toggleAutoplay()
   {
      isPause = !isPause;
      print(isPause);
      notifyListeners();
   }
}
```

I printed couple of statements to debug and every time I toggle the switch the function is being called as the values will change from false to true, however, it is not notifying the change. Any idea on whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

can you try add "*lazy*" : false to *ChangeNotifierProvider* ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use setState in onChange method

```
return ChangeNotifierProvider<AutoplayToggle>(
  create: (context) => AutoplayToggle(),
  child: Consumer<AutoplayToggle>(
    builder: (context, provider, child) {
      return Container(
       color: provider.isPause ? accent : primary,
        width: 45,
        child: Switch.adaptive(
          value: provider.isPause,
          onChanged: (value) async {
            await UserPrefs.setAutoplay(isPause);
            provider.toggleAutoplay();
          },
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```